Third order estimate for linear elliptic equations
Let $\lambda < A < \Lambda$ be a constant symmetric matrix and $u$ be a  $C^{\infty}$(elliptic regularity gives smooth solutions) solution of $\text{div} A \nabla u = 0$. Let $S_1$ be a sphere of radius $1$ and $B_1$ a ball of radius $1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Without using any change of variables, can one show either one of the following to hold true?
$$ \langle A \nabla \Delta u, A \nabla u \rangle \geq 0  \quad \text{OR} \int_{S_1} \langle A \nabla \Delta u, A \nabla u \rangle d\sigma \geq 0 \quad \text{OR} \int_{B_1} \langle A \nabla \Delta u, A \nabla u \rangle dx \geq 0?$$
In the case $A$ is identity matrix, then $\langle A \nabla \Delta u, A \nabla u \rangle  = \langle  \nabla \Delta u,  \nabla u \rangle =0$ pointwise since $u$ is harmonic.
